# Microsoft Word shows citation in code field format

Tags: microsoft-word, citations, endnote

I'm using MS Word 2021 and EndNote 20. I'm writing a scientific paper that needs citations. but an exception happened now, which is like this:
[image]
The citation is showing up like field codes! I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to change the citation to field results instead of field codes but it didn't work.

How can I fix it?

---

Expected Output (something like this):
[image]

Comment: Does Fn+Alt+F9 work?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon No.

Comment: Check with Endnote support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by updating the citations. Steps to solve:

1. Open MS Word
2. Go to **EndNote 20** tab
3. Click on **Update Citations and Bibliography**